# Decouple Top-Level MFC Dialogs

Tags: c++, mfc

I am working with MFC and C++ and am unsure of how to properly decouple two top-level dialogs that need to interact with each other. Specifically, one of the dialogs(say dialog X) should perform an action in response to a button click on the other dialog(say dialog Y). The current way this is implemented in the code base is that Y's constructor takes as an argument a pointer to X. It then uses this pointer to perform the action on X when its own button is clicked. This seems like an unreasonable restriction on what would otherwise be a generic dialog. What I was hoping to be able to do was have X register some sort of listener for button click messages from Y. Unfortunately, I haven't found anything that would suggest that this is possible.

Two alternatives that I have considered:

1. Register a custom message and send it from Y to X (highly coupled...)
2. Broadcast a message and listen for it in X (seems excessive)

I am relatively new to MFC and am not particularly familiar with the idioms or best practices of the MFC community. I would greatly appreciate any ideas or suggestions on how to properly decouple the dialogs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest approach is to specify custom [WM_APP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644930%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)+x messages and maintain a list of `HWND` to be notified when your event occurs. However, a more modern approach is the [Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). This involves creating an `IObserver` and an `ISubject` interface which pretty much work in the same way. Your dialogs would then implement these interfaces. The advantage of this solution is that you can have non-HWND based classes listening for your events. Also, sending messages is more costly.